# Como alternar as linhas de um relatório com cores personalizadas Crystal Reports e C# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

No relatório que estou fazendo, já consegui alternar as cores fazendo da seguinte forma: ***Acesso o Menu:*** `Crystal Reports` - `Report` - `Section Expert`
Selecione a *`section`* `Details` e clique na aba `Color`
Clique no botão formula **`x-2`**, vai abir o editor de formula

Coloque o seguinte código:

```
if (RecordNumber mod 2) = 0 then crNoColor else crSilver
```

O problema, é que a cor cinzenta (`crSilver`) está escura demais, preciso obter um cinzento mais claro, que não foge muito do branco.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de personalizar cores, e atribuir nomes a elas e posteriormente usar estes nomes no Crystal Reports?
Ou se existe uma lista de cores com os seus respectivos nomes no `Crystal Reports`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem a function 
Color (red, green, blue)

Pode ter um auxilio em uma edição normal de de cor , botão "mais" edite a cor como quiser e use os parâmetros vermelho , verde e azul na function citada.

obs : Faço "zebrado" com crSilver mas não acho escuro demais

Comment: Obrigadão @Motta! Usei "Color(223,223,223)" e ficou do jeito que queria. Valeu irmão!